# attempting to call function from separate class in appdelegate

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, appdelegate

im trying to save arrays when the app closes, using userdefaults, but i get this error when i call the method in the app delegate "Missing argument for parameter 'data' in call"

code from separate class:

```
func saveDataForKey(key: String, data: [Item]){
      let arrayData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(data)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(arrayData, forKey: ArrayKey)
}
```

code from app delegate:

```
var ds = DataStore()//this is the separate class

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

    ds.saveDataForKey(key: String, data: [Item])//this is where i get the error   
}
```

Comment: In app delegate, while calling saveDataForKey() you need to pass the parameters for that function call. Why you are not passing the parameters?

Comment: i thought '(key: String, data: [Item])' was the parameters. what would i use in its place?

Comment: parameters would be the value you want to save in userdefaults

Comment: this function saves 10 arrays. so what exactly would that value be?

Comment: Let me repeat what others have pointed out in a different way.  In the app delegate, when calling saveDataForKey(), you are not passing parameters, you are just repeating the function signature.  That is not a correct syntax in Swift (or any other language).  Also you do not use the app delegate to perform this operation.  You should always prefer to use the NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: iterate for loop for that 10 arrays and pass the value.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the app delegate for that.  Use the NSNotificationCenter instead.  In your class (`DataStore` presumably) register to listen to system notifications such as `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`. You can use either a selector or a block.  For example (selector) you can do:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: "WRITE A METHOD AS EXPLAINED BELOW",
            name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification,
          object: nil)
```

In this case the selector is a method that can only take an `NSNotification` as its only input. You probably need to wrap your `saveDataForKey` in such method.